# JavaFx ObservableList want to change the color of each cells

Tags: listview, javafx, observablelist

Here is what I am doing.

```
ListView listView = new ListView();
listView.setBackground(new Background(new 
BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK,CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
listView.setPrefSize(400,450);
ObservableList list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
list.add(label);
list.add(label2);
listView.setItems(list);
```

So I can change the background color of listView but the problem is when I am doing this listView.setItems(list); it is not showing me the background color.It is actually hiding it. So, instead of changing the background of listView, I think I should change the color of observable list cells but I have no clue how to do that. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Note: you never-ever add controls as listItems, instead you add data and - if you need custom visuals - a custom cellFactory that creates cells which configure themselves as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kleopatra said, you can't add Components as items. The items must be objects with data only.

If you are trying to add Label's I'm assuming that you want to show a String on each Cell, so you should be doing something like:

```
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
listView.setPrefSize(400,450);
listView.getItems().addAll("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
```

To customize the appearance is better just to use css.

```
.list-cell { -fx-text-fill: black; }
.list-cell:odd { -fx-background-color: white;}
.list-cell:even { -fx-background-color: #8f8; }
```

And... If you want to customize how each cell will be shown and behave you set a Cell factory like this:

```
listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
            ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    setGraphic(null);

                    if (empty || item == null) {
                        setText(null);
                    }
                    else {
                        setText((String) item);
                    }
                }
            };

            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Usually when creating a Cell Factory it's common to override the updateItem (to configure the cell to reflect the item content) and commitEdit (to persist in the item the result of the cell edition).